# Basic Vanilla Javascript example not working

Tags: javascript

Would someone please explain why this isn't working?

HTML

```
<p>
    <button class="selectable">Button</button>
</p>
```

Javascript

```
var selectable = document.getElementsByClassName('selectable');

selectable.onclick = function() {
    alert("Success");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qpmsw5yg/

Thanks,

Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a collection. If you want to set a handler on a node, you have to specify an individual node.

```
function onSelectableClick() {
    alert('Success');
}

var selectables = document.getElementsByClassName('selectable');
for (var i = 0; i < selectables.length; i++) {
    selectables[i].onclick = onSelectableClick;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, works perfect.  Not enough credentials to mark as answer yet.

Answer (score 3):

`selectable` is a `HTMLCollection` not an `Element`. So you should listen to `selectable[0]`.

Updated JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/NeekGerd/qpmsw5yg/1/

Comment: This answer worked, thank you.  Would also be helpful to know how to apply to all which the answer below showed using a loop.  Thanks to everyone!